# Detect mouse wheel over SKCanvasView

Tags: maui, skiasharp

I have a MAUI application for viewing images. Images are rendered using SKCanvasView. I wanted to add zoom functionality which, on windows, would work using mouse wheel. However I wasn't able to find a way to do it. The closes gesture to what I'm looking for seems to be PinchGesture, but mouse wheel doesn't get translated to it. I found that some controls have `PointerWheelChanged` event, but `SKCanvasView` is not one of them. I also heard of writing custom dependency services and handlers for this purpose, but no actual examples of such for mouse wheel.

I have a hunch that this is impossible in MAUI for now (unless I go really low level and tap into Windows APIs), but if someone knows a way how to make this work, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I suspect your hunch is correct. You likely need to solve this in Windows code. That might not be as low level as you fear. On Windows, Maui becomes Win UI 3 (Windows Desktop App SDK) code. Somewhere there is an example of customizing the handler for the WinUI window that your app runs in. Find that, and lookup WinUI3 docs re mouse wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `PointerWheelChanged` event to the windows platform view of the `SKCanvasView`. Such as：

In the xaml:

```
<sk:SKCanvasView x:Name="skview" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300"/>
```

And in the page's code behind:

```
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
            var view = skview.Handler.PlatformView as SkiaSharp.Views.Windows.SKXamlCanvas;
            view.PointerWheelChanged += ( s, e) =>
            {

            };
#endif
      }
```

I have tested this and it can detect the mouse wheel over SKCanvasView.